# Filtros condicionales utilizando linq

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2017

Trabajo en una app Windows Forms, C#, Visual Studio 2019, Sql Server 2014

Si no le paso un parámetro lo toma como null

```
public IEnumerable<UniversalExtend> SelectOrdenesDeVenta(CriteriaOrdenVenta filter)
    {
        using (var context = new BusinessContext())
        {
            var result = from ov in context.OrdenVentas
                         join c in context.Clientes on ov.ClienteId equals c.ClienteId
                         where
                             (filter.Codigo == null || ov.CodigoNumerico.Contains(filter.Codigo))
                             ||
                             (!filter.ClienteId.HasValue || ov.ClienteId.Equals(filter.ClienteId.Value))
                             ||
                             (filter.FechaEmision == null || ov.FechaEmision >= filter.FechaEmision)
                             ||
                             (filter.FechaCaducidad == null || ov.FechaCaducidad <= filter.FechaCaducidad)
                         select
                             new UniversalExtend()
                             {
                                 NumeroComprobante = ov.NumeroComprobante,
                                 Descripcion = c.RazonSocial,
                                 FechaEmision = ov.FechaEmision,
                                 FechaCaducidad = ov.FechaCaducidad,
                                 EstadoId = ov.Estado,
                                 Total = ov.Total
                             };
            return result.ToList();
        }
    }
```

El problema que tengo que el resultado que me da es toda la tabla como si hubiera hecho un `select * from tabla` pero como parámetro estoy usando el campo `CodigoNumerico` el cual le envio un string `000000001`

Revisando en el profiler el query que se construye es el siguiente

```
xec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[Estado] AS [Estado], 
[Extent1].[NumeroComprobante] AS [NumeroComprobante], 
[Extent2].[RazonSocial] AS [RazonSocial], 
[Extent1].[FechaEmision] AS [FechaEmision], 
[Extent1].[FechaCaducidad] AS [FechaCaducidad], 
[Extent1].[Total] AS [Total]
FROM  [dbo].[OrdenVentas] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Clientes] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ClienteId] = [Extent2].[ClienteId]
WHERE (@p__linq__0 IS NULL) OR ([Extent1].[CodigoNumerico] LIKE @p__linq__1 ESCAPE ''~'') OR (@p__linq__2 IS NULL) OR ([Extent1].[ClienteId] = @p__linq__3) OR (@p__linq__4 IS NULL) OR ([Extent1].[FechaEmision] >= @p__linq__5) OR (@p__linq__6 IS NULL) OR ([Extent1].[FechaCaducidad] <= @p__linq__7)',N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__1 varchar(8000),@p__linq__2 int,@p__linq__3 int,@p__linq__4 datetime2(7),@p__linq__5 datetime2(7),@p__linq__6 datetime2(7),@p__linq__7 datetime2(7)',@p__linq__0=N'000000001',@p__linq__1='%000000001%',@p__linq__2=NULL,@p__linq__3=NULL,@p__linq__4=NULL,@p__linq__5=NULL,@p__linq__6=NULL,@p__linq__7=NULL
```

Se repite dos veces el parámetro que le envio, ¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

Saludos!

Comment: Estas usando Or en cada condicion, basta con que una de las propiedades de *filter* sea null para que te traiga toda la tabla.
Si lo que deseas es anexar condiciones para filtros adicionales debes usar And en vez de Or

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando tienes este tipo de problema lo principal es simplificar la query y probar con algo simple para ver como se comporta, entonces empieza con algo como ser

```
var result = from ov in context.OrdenVentas
             where
                 (filter.Codigo == null 
                        || ov.CodigoNumerico.Contains(filter.Codigo))
                 &&(!filter.ClienteId.HasValue 
                        || ov.ClienteId.Equals(filter.ClienteId.Value))
             select ov;
```

sin join, sin un select especifico, solo te centras en el where y con solo dos campos para ver si estos aplican el filtro que esperas

Veras que cambie el `||` que unes los diferentes campos por un `&&`

De esta forma encontraras como responde y luego vas agregando los demas campos y los campos concretos para el select

Comment: Gracias Leandro, soluciono mi problema.